# HTTP 500 error when sending XML to server

Tags: java, xml, http

I am trying to send an XML file to my RESTful web server, and receive a XML file in return, however, I am getting a 500 error.

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:
>   http://sps-psa-240:8080/NMCJWS/rest/jmsmon2/pub   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
>     at SendXML.send(SendXML.java:151)
>         at SendXML.main(SendXML.java:39)

Line 151 is `InputStream response = uc.getInputStream();`

If I uncomment `System.out.println(((HttpURLConnection) uc).getResponseCode());`, 
then I get the same error on `OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(uc.getOutputStream());`

I know the server works because a coworker has this working in Obj-C.

Here is my code:

```
public class SendXML 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, XPathExpressionException, ParserConfigurationException, 
                                                IOException, TransformerException 
    {   
        String xml = generateXML("AC24", "/fa/gdscc/dss24-apc");
        send("localhost", xml); 
    }

    public static String generateXML(String conn, String funcAddr) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, 
                                                IOException, XPathExpressionException, TransformerException 
    {
        /*
         * <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <JMSMON2Req>
                <SubItem UID="iPAD-2031e616-de74-44a7-9292-3745d2b1ba21">
                    <FuncAddr>/fa/gdscc/con1-ac25</FuncAddr>
                    <ItemName>AZANG</ItemName>
                    <ItemName>ELANG</ItemName>
                    <Metadata key="UID">iPAD-2031e616-de74-44a7-9292-3745d2b1ba21</Metadata>
                    <Metadata key="CONN">1</Metadata>
                </SubItem>
            </JMSMON2Req>
         */

        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); // never forget this!
        DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse("http://sps-psa-240:8080/NMCWS/rest/conn/subsys/prof?ss=" + conn + "&pt=IPAD_DASHBOARD");

        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/SubscrProf/DataItem/DataItemName");

        Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

        //build xml
        Document output = builder.newDocument();

        //create root
        org.w3c.dom.Element root = output.createElement("JMSMON2Req");
        output.appendChild(root);

            //create subitem
            org.w3c.dom.Element subItemNode = output.createElement("SubItem");
            subItemNode.setAttribute("UID", "IPAD-CN1-DSS26-SC151-PN230-AC26");
            root.appendChild(subItemNode);

                //create funcAddr
                org.w3c.dom.Element funcAddrNode = output.createElement("FuncAddr");
                Text text = output.createTextNode(funcAddr);
                funcAddrNode.appendChild(text);
                subItemNode.appendChild(funcAddrNode);

                //create itemname
                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) 
                {
                    org.w3c.dom.Element itemNameNode = output.createElement("SubItem");
                    text = output.createTextNode(nodes.item(i).getTextContent());
                    itemNameNode.appendChild(text);
                    subItemNode.appendChild(itemNameNode);
                }

                //create metadata uid
                org.w3c.dom.Element metaDataNode = output.createElement("Metadata");
                metaDataNode.setAttribute("key", "UID");
                text = output.createTextNode("IPAD-CN1-DSS26-SC151-PN230-AC26");
                metaDataNode.appendChild(text);
                subItemNode.appendChild(metaDataNode);

                //create metadata conn
                org.w3c.dom.Element metaDataNode2 = output.createElement("Metadata");
                metaDataNode2.setAttribute("key", "CONN");
                text = output.createTextNode("4");
                metaDataNode2.appendChild(text);
                subItemNode.appendChild(metaDataNode2);

        /////////////////
        //Output the XML

        //set up a transformer
        TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        //create string from xml tree
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult out = new StreamResult(sw);
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(output);

        trans.transform(source, out);
        String xmlString = sw.toString();

        //print xml
        System.out.println("Here's the xml:\n" + xmlString);

        return xmlString;
    }

    public static void send(String urladdress, String file) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
    {
        String charset = "UTF-8";
        String s = URLEncoder.encode(file, charset);

        // Open the connection and prepare to POST
        URLConnection uc = new URL(urladdress).openConnection();
        uc.setDoOutput(true);
        uc.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
        uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/xml");

        try
        {
            //System.out.println(((HttpURLConnection) uc).getResponseCode());
            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(uc.getOutputStream());
            out.write(s);
            out.flush();

            InputStream response = uc.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response));
            String line;

            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.println(line);


            out.close();
            response.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        { 
            e.printStackTrace();    // should do real exception handling
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: HTTP 500 usually means that the server code threw an exception (often caused by a bug in the server code which in turn can be triggered by bad user input). Read the server logs. What is it telling about the cause of the HTTP 500 error? *That* is then the answer to your question.

Comment: I'm not in a position to test, but you may need to close the output stream before reading the input.

Comment: Closing output stream before reading input didnt fix it.

Comment: Verify that your generated XML is the same as your colleagues that is working. I do notice you use the OMIT_XML_DECLARATION property with a 'yes' value, but your commented out sample has that declaration. Beyond that, you'll have to view the server logs as others have suggested and add that error detail to your question.

Comment: If I were to add `org.w3c.dom.Element root = output.createElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");`, I get a INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified. This is because there are spaces in the name. Anyway to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem.  I had to encode xmlString in UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Look at the logs on the server.  What is causing the 500 error?

Is this a RESTful web service, or a SOAP web service you're submitting to?

Consider using some sort of XML<->Object framework like [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) or [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).

Consider using some sort of RESTful web service framework like [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) or [RestEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy).

Consider using some sort of SOAP framework like [JAX-WS](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/) or [Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/)

Comment: We're all still wondering what the server log shows.  Also if you're using a rest framework, there is possibly some additional debugging you can turn on, such as a [LoggingFilter](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.8/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/filter/LoggingFilter.html) in jersey.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the right encoding.
`URLEncoder.encode` is making the content safe for transfer as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', but you probably want to use UTF-8.

Also, `new OutputStreamWriter(...)` should specify the desired encoding. You are currently using the standard platform encoding which is probably iso-8859-1.

Third, don't try to mess around with URLConnection yourself, if there are plenty of libs around there, that can make you life easier.

Here is the send method done in Resty (Disclaimer: I'm the author of it). HTTPClient is another choice to consider as are other client-side libraries.

```
import us.monoid.web.Resty;
import static us.monoid.web.Resty.*;

Resty r = new Resty();
String result = r.text(urladdress, new Content("text/xml", file.getBytes("UTF-8"))).toString();
```

Comment: no, it doesn't. You are probably just lucky because ISO-8859-1 is a valid subset of UTF-8 and you are encoding it first using RFC1738. While the content may survive intact, the server will have no clue you used RFC1738 on the content.

Comment: So what would I change this to? `String charset = "UTF-8";
  String s = URLEncoder.encode(file, charset);`?

Comment: why do you think you have to URL encode it? It is not part of an URL and the MIME type is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Use new OutputStreamWriter(stream, "UTF-8")