# Post an SOAP XML file to Webservice

Tags: c#, xml, post, soap

I am having SOAP XML file which i need to POST it to Web Service in C#. I need to call the Webservice with a URL from a console app and read the response. Iam always getting HTTP 500. Internal Server Error

Comment: well, maybe there is something wrong in server code which makes it respond 500?

Comment: I have a method in web service which accepts two string variables. When i test it by str1=abc&str2=gfh, It works. When i try to test the same by passing xml file, It fails.

Comment: have you tested them? Error 500 means, that server has some serious problem with processing request. So, if you send serialized entity - maybe it's something with serialization? in case of two strings - ensure that both of them are present

Comment: You need to give us more information.  We can't tell what is happening just from the server error number.  What does your XML look like?  What is the exception shown in the error, if any?

Comment: That being said, check to make sure your problem isn't a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670860/http-500-error-when-sending-xml-to-server